# Comparing Two Excel Sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, cells

I Have Two Excel Sheets wherein one is a copy of the other. I had updated Data in both Sheets quiet sometime back but since they had the same name, I am now confused which one was updated later with data. So Can I compare both the sheets in a way to know which might contain more data (in its cells) than the other ?

Comment: Did you check the properties of each file? Right-click on the sheet on Explorer and  check in the details

Comment: yes I have checked.. but the thing is that the files are stored on two different systems...Seems to be confusing..